Are jets like the F86 still viable on the modern battlefield today?
Are jets like the F86 still viable on the modern battlefield today? Would it be better to build large numbers of older but cheaper jets such as the F86 in the thousands to swarm and overwhelm the enemy through sheer numbers rather than relying on more advanced but far more expensive jets that could only be build in limited numbers. As the saying goes quantity has a quality on its own.

You may want to consider that "overwhelm the enemy through numbers" is an amazingly bland way to say "get hundreds or thousands of highly trained soldiers killed for small gains". Even if you have no morals regarding the death of soldiers, pilots each take 18-24 months to train, and then you'll have to defend those losses to the government and the thousands of families who watched you hurl their sons into a meat grinder. Should we dispense with guns and just outfit the infantry with knives instead? They're much cheaper, and quantity has a quality of its own!

During the battle of Britain in 1940, the Luftwaffe had superior numbers of aircraft and much more experienced pilots. Both sides were able to produce new aircraft equally quickly. One of the major factors that helped Britain to survive to conflict was that most aircraft were shot down over British controlled territory which meant British pilots could be rescued and put back into the air, while German pilots were put into POW camps and so removed from the war.
Quantity alone doesn't cut it. A dozen F16's could have destroyed the Luftwaffe (or the RAF) without loss.

The most expensive part of an F86 swarm would be the pilots- and it would be unaffordable. Once you ditch the pilots, it makes little sense to have the individual elements of the swarm be as large as an F86.

I'm sure it's much much simpler and cheaper to train an early jet pilot like the F86 pilot compared to training a modern jet pilot such as the F16. After all our forefathers have done so during the 50s and 60s without issues

The "cost" involved has little to do with money/currency.

@WenHuiWong - The F16 is a much, much easier jet to fly then the F86. Modern jets are designed to allow the pilot to indicate what they want to achieve and the jet works out how to do it, which takes a huge amount of workload off the pilot, leaving them free(er) to worry about the fight.

@WenHuiWong a lot of the 50s and 60s pilots died due accidents coming from poorly understood aerodynamics and design https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_F-104_Starfighter#Safety_record https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_F-86_Sabre#Flying_characteristics. For your proposed human wave fighter you want modern a mass produced fly by wire system + modern aerodynamic design to get an easy to train for system.

The F86 sabre is good enough for thar task. I don't see why we can't continue to use the F86.
